# con esta linea de codigo puedo subir una foto a mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql, json

este es el codigo donde se reciben los datos del otro formulario
pero no me almacena la informacion de la foto, los demas datos si ingresan bien

```html
<?php
 if (empty($_POST['name'])){
  $errors[] = "Ingresa el nombre del producto.";
 } elseif (!empty($_POST['name'])){
 require_once ("../conexion.php");//Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos
 // escaping, additionally removing everything that could be (html/javascript-) code
    $prod_code = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["code"],ENT_QUOTES)));
 $prod_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["name"],ENT_QUOTES)));
 $prod_ctry = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["category"],ENT_QUOTES)));
 $stock = intval($_POST["stock"]);
 $prod_img = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_FILES["prod_img"],ENT_QUOTES)));
 $price = floatval($_POST["price"]);
 

 // REGISTER data into database
 $nombrefoto = $_FILES["prod_img"]["name"];
    $ruta = $_FILES["prod_img"]["tmp_name"]; //localizacion actual del archivo
    $destino = "../../../Imagenes/Fotos/".$nombrefoto; //lugar en el que se quiere copiar
    copy($ruta, $destino);//es para realizar la copia del archivo
    
    $sql = "INSERT INTO tblprod(id, prod_code, prod_name, prod_ctry, prod_qty, prod_img price) VALUES (NULL,'$prod_code','$prod_name','$prod_ctry','$stock', '$nombrefoto',$price')";
    $query = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
    // if product has been added successfully
    if ($query) {
        $messages[] = "El producto ha sido guardado con éxito.";
    } else {
        $errors[] = "Lo sentimos, el registro falló. Por favor, regrese y vuelva a intentarlo.";
    }
  
 } else 
 {
  $errors[] = "desconocido.";
 }
if (isset($errors)){
   
   ?>
   <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
     <strong>Error!</strong> 
     <?php
      foreach ($errors as $error) {
        echo $error;
       }
      ?>
   </div>
   <?php
   }
   if (isset($messages)){
    
    ?>
    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
      <strong>¡Bien hecho!</strong>
      <?php
       foreach ($messages as $message) {
         echo $message;
        }
       ?>
    </div>
    <?php
   }
?>
```

Tengo estas lineas de código para subir imágenes a *mysql* con *json* pero me arroja un error

```
$prod_img = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_POST["prod_img"],ENT_QUOTES)));
```

Comment: Y cual es el error que arroja? dale un vistazo a este articulo: [¿Como preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: me dice que no esta definida la variable Notice: Undefined index: prod_img in C:\xampp\htdocs\Cerberos\Formularios\updateprod\ajax\guardar_producto.php

Comment: Lo que te dice esa información es que tu código esta esperando un campo "prod_img" me imagino que es un input tipo file, entonces no se esta enviando, si has seleccionado la imagen? el input tiene ese atributo name?

Comment: Por lo regular no se suben imágenes a las bases de datos, lo que se sube es el archivo en algún directorio y lo que se almacena en la bd es la ruta hacia ese archivo.

Comment: si se llama asi mi input <div class="photo">
      <label for="foto">Foto</label>
             <div class="prevPhoto">
             <span class="delPhoto notBlock">X</span>
             <label for="foto"></label>
             </div>
             <div class="upimg">
             <input type="file" name="prod_img" id="foto">
             </div>
             <div id="form_alert"></div>

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y añade el código que esta recibiendo el php, no pongas passwords ni nada de eso, para ver como es que estar recibiendo los datos.

Answer (score 0):

en el formulario asegurate que tenga agregado "multipart/form-data":

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="#a donde lo mandes" method="POST">
```

y te dice que no esta definida ya que como es un archivo se trabaja con "$_FILES" no con $_POST seria algo como:

```
$prod_img = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,(strip_tags($_FILES["prod_img"],ENT_QUOTES)));
```

Comment: ya le modifique el POST por FILES he igual me arroja el mismo error.

Answer (score 0):

revisando el código que pusiste,  Revisa la consulta SQL, te falta una coma despues de prod_img:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tblprod(id, prod_code, prod_name, prod_ctry, prod_qty, prod_img price) VALUES (NULL,'$prod_code','$prod_name','$prod_ctry','$stock', '$nombrefoto',$price')";
```

Debería quedar así:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tblprod(id, prod_code, prod_name, prod_ctry, prod_qty, prod_img, price) VALUES (NULL,'$prod_code','$prod_name','$prod_ctry','$stock', '$nombrefoto','$price')";
```

Haz el cambio y comenta, saludos!

Bueno el error creo esta en que estas pasando el mysqli_real_escape_string al $_FILES, remueve esa linea y en lugar de ellos haz una validación como isset($_FILES['img_prod']) adicionalmente podrías hacer una validación de tipo de archivo.

```
<?php
if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
  $errors[] = "Ingresa el nombre del producto.";
} elseif (!empty($_POST['name'])) {
  require_once("../conexion.php"); //Contiene funcion que conecta a la base de datos
  // escaping, additionally removing everything that could be (html/javascript-) code
  $prod_code = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, (strip_tags($_POST["code"], ENT_QUOTES)));
  $prod_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, (strip_tags($_POST["name"], ENT_QUOTES)));
  $prod_ctry = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, (strip_tags($_POST["category"], ENT_QUOTES)));
  $stock = intval($_POST["stock"]);
  // $prod_img = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, (strip_tags($_FILES["prod_img"], ENT_QUOTES)));
  $price = floatval($_POST["price"]);
  if (isset($_FILES["prod_img"]['tmp_name'])) {
    // REGISTER data into database
    $nombrefoto = $_FILES["prod_img"]["name"];
    $ruta = $_FILES["prod_img"]["tmp_name"]; //localizacion actual del archivo
    $destino = "../../../Imagenes/Fotos/" . $nombrefoto; //lugar en el que se quiere copiar
    copy($ruta, $destino); //es para realizar la copia del archivo

    $sql = "INSERT INTO tblprod(id, prod_code, prod_name, prod_ctry, prod_qty, prod_img, price) VALUES (NULL,'$prod_code','$prod_name','$prod_ctry','$stock', '$nombrefoto','$price')";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    // if product has been added successfully
    if ($query) {
      $messages[] = "El producto ha sido guardado con éxito.";
    } else {
      $errors[] = "Lo sentimos, el registro falló. Por favor, regrese y vuelva a intentarlo.";
    }
  } else {

    $errors[] = "Lo sentimos, el registro falló. Falta imagen de producto.";

  }

} else {
  $errors[] = "desconocido.";
}
if (isset($errors)) {

?>
  <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <strong>Error!</strong>
    <?php
    foreach ($errors as $error) {
      echo $error;
    }
    ?>
  </div>
<?php
}
if (isset($messages)) {

?>
  <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <strong>¡Bien hecho!</strong>
    <?php
    foreach ($messages as $message) {
      echo $message;
    }
    ?>
  </div>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: me arroja los notice igual y almacena el resto de la informacion menos la foto.

Comment: Falta una comilla antes del value $price, ya edite la sentencia $sql copiala y reemplazala en en tú código.

Comment: igual me arroja los mismos notice.

Comment: Actualice mi respuesta, revisala por favor, saludos.

Comment: ya lo modifique, no me arroja ningun error de programacion, pero me dice error desconocido he igual no almacena la imagen.